# Custom Struct Property Editor Add Setter and Listener

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have been struggling with this for a while and would really appreciate some guidance.

The goal is to create a dropdown list/combo box that contains strings that the user can select in the editor. This is to extend details customization.

I have created a custom structure like so.

```
USTRUCT()
struct FTaskComponentData
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    TArray<FString>                                             Names;

};
```

Then I have created a class to implement the IPropertyTypeCustomization like so: 
(Header file):

```
class FTaskComponentDataCustomization : public IPropertyTypeCustomization
{
public:
    static TSharedRef<IPropertyTypeCustomization> MakeInstance();

    /** IPropertyTypeCustomization interface */
    virtual void CustomizeHeader(TSharedRef<class IPropertyHandle> StructPropertyHandle, class FDetailWidgetRow& HeaderRow, IPropertyTypeCustomizationUtils& StructCustomizationUtils) override;
    virtual void CustomizeChildren(TSharedRef<class IPropertyHandle> StructPropertyHandle, class IDetailChildrenBuilder& StructBuilder, IPropertyTypeCustomizationUtils& StructCustomizationUtils) override;

private:
    TSharedPtr<IPropertyHandle> UPropertyTaskNameHandle;

    /** Visibility delegate for the various methods of calculating magnitude */
    EVisibility GetPropertyVisibility(UProperty* InProperty) const;
};
```

(Source file):

```
TSharedRef<IPropertyTypeCustomization> FTaskComponentDataCustomization::MakeInstance()
{
    return MakeShareable(new FTaskComponentDataCustomization());
}

void FTaskComponentDataCustomization::CustomizeHeader(TSharedRef<class IPropertyHandle> StructPropertyHandle, class FDetailWidgetRow& HeaderRow, IPropertyTypeCustomizationUtils& StructCustomizationUtils)
{
    uint32 NumChildren;
    StructPropertyHandle->GetNumChildren(NumChildren);

    for (uint32 ChildIndex = 0; ChildIndex < NumChildren; ++ChildIndex)
    {
        const TSharedRef< IPropertyHandle > ChildHandle = StructPropertyHandle->GetChildHandle(ChildIndex).ToSharedRef();

        if (ChildHandle->GetProperty()->GetName() == TEXT("Names"))
        {
            UPropertyTaskNameHandle = ChildHandle;
        }
    }

    check(UPropertyTaskNameHandle.IsValid());


    static TArray< TSharedPtr<FString>> something;

    something.Add(TSharedPtr<FString>(new FString("One")));
    something.Add(TSharedPtr<FString>(new FString("Two")));
    something.Add(TSharedPtr<FString>(new FString("Three")));


    HeaderRow.NameContent()
        [
            StructPropertyHandle->CreatePropertyNameWidget(LOCTEXT("Task", "Task Names"), LOCTEXT("IDK","IDK"), false, true, false)
        ]
    .ValueContent()
        .MinDesiredWidth(250)
        [
            SNew(STextComboBox)
            .OptionsSource(&something)
        ];
}

void FTaskComponentDataCustomization::CustomizeChildren(TSharedRef<class IPropertyHandle> StructPropertyHandle, class IDetailChildrenBuilder& StructBuilder, IPropertyTypeCustomizationUtils& StructCustomizationUtils)
{
}


EVisibility FTaskComponentDataCustomization::GetPropertyVisibility(UProperty* InProperty) const {
    return EVisibility::Visible;
}
```

I have then included this custom structure in my component subclass like this:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Planning | Task")
FTaskComponentData                          TaskData;
```

I then register with the FPropertyEditorModule like so:

```
FPropertyEditorModule& PropertyModule = FModuleManager::LoadModuleChecked<FPropertyEditorModule>("PropertyEditor");

    //Custom properties
    PropertyModule.RegisterCustomPropertyTypeLayout("TaskComponentData", FOnGetPropertyTypeCustomizationInstance::CreateStatic(&FTaskComponentDataCustomization::MakeInstance));
```

At this point, the desired combo box shows up.. I have 2 questions:

1) How can I set TArray so that I can update the data members with different strings?

2) How do I register the property change listener? Right now, none of the property change listeners are fired from my component when I try to select values from my combobox.

Or where do I got to dig up any of this functionality?

Comment: You provide very complex solution. What do you think about creating enum class, and than in component use it as UPROPERTY ``TEnumAsByte<EClassName::Type>`` ? In editor you will be able to choose one of enum value (with custom DisplayName UMETA). Property change listeners will works normally and whatmore comparing enums is much faster than strings.